# Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager' in your configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-transactions, spring-cloud-task

I am developing a spring cloud task application using spring cloud task and spring batch libraries. I also created a spring boot library containing spring cloud task and spring batch configurations and added this library as a dependent on spring cloud task project. I get the following error while running the application

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager' in your configuration.
```

Main class:

```
import com.batch.common.config.batchcommonconfig.CronJobConfig;
import com.batch.common.config.batchcommonconfig.DbConfig;
import com.batch.common.config.batchcommonconfig.TaskJobConfig;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.EnableTask;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.SimpleTaskAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableTask
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SimpleTaskAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SpringBatchApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBatchApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

DemoCronJobConfiguration class

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.*;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.DefaultTransactionAttribute;
import org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@Import({CronJobConfig.class,
    TaskJobConfig.class,DbConfig.class})
public class DemoCronJobConfiguration {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Qualifier("h2DataSource")
    private DataSource h2DataSource;


    @Autowired
    private JtaTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Bean
    public Job demoJob(@Autowired JobRepository batchJobRepository) {
        SimpleJob job = new SimpleJob("demoJob");
        String runParameter = "run.id";
        job.setSteps(java.util.Arrays.asList(demoJobStep(batchJobRepository)));
        job.setJobRepository(batchJobRepository);
        job.setJobParametersIncrementer(new JobParametersIncrementer() {
            @Override
            public JobParameters getNext(JobParameters parameters) {
                if (parameters==null || parameters.isEmpty()) {
                    return new JobParametersBuilder().addLong(runParameter, 1L).toJobParameters();
                }
                long id = parameters.getLong(runParameter,1L) + 1;
                return new JobParametersBuilder().addLong(runParameter, id).toJobParameters();
            }
        });
        logger.info("------job instance created-------");
        return job;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step demoJobStep(@Autowired JobRepository batchJobRepository) {
        DefaultTransactionAttribute attribute = new DefaultTransactionAttribute();
        attribute.setTimeout(2000);

        TaskletStep step = new TaskletStep("demoJobStep");
        step.setTasklet(generateTasklet());
        step.setJobRepository(batchJobRepository);
        transactionManager.setAllowCustomIsolationLevels(true);
        step.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        step.setTransactionAttribute(attribute);
        return step;
    }

    @Bean
    public DemoCronJobTasklet generateTasklet(){

        return new DemoCronJobTasklet();
    }
}
```

DemoCronJobTasklet class:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class DemoCronJobTasklet implements Tasklet {
    private static Logger logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoCronJobTasklet.class);

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
            logger.info("hello demo job");
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

Batch Application project pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.batch.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>batch-application</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>batch-application</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-task</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.batch.common.config</groupId>
            <artifactId>batch-common-config</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-task-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>repackage</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Batch common library classes:

CronJobConfig class:

```
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor;
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.aop.target.AbstractLazyCreationTargetSource;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.JobRegistry;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobOperator;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

@EnableConfigurationProperties(BatchProperties.class)
@Configuration
public class CronJobConfig {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private boolean initialized = false;

    @Bean
    public JobOperator jobOperator(final JobLauncher jobLauncher, final JobExplorer jobExplorer,
                                   final JobRepository jobRepository, final JobRegistry jobRegistry) {

        SimpleJobOperator simpleJobOperator = new SimpleJobOperator();
        simpleJobOperator.setJobExplorer(jobExplorer);
        simpleJobOperator.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
        simpleJobOperator.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        simpleJobOperator.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        return simpleJobOperator;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobExplorerFactoryBean jobExplorer(@Qualifier("h2DataSource") final DataSource dataSource) {

        JobExplorerFactoryBean jobExplorerFactoryBean = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
        jobExplorerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        jobExplorerFactoryBean.setTablePrefix("BATCH_");
        return  jobExplorerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public MapJobRegistry jobRegistry() {
        return new MapJobRegistry();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegisterBeanPostProcess(final JobRegistry jobRegistry)  {
        JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
        jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        return  jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        launcher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        launcher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return launcher;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(@Qualifier("h2DataSource") DataSource dataSource,
                                       @Qualifier("transactionManager") JtaTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepo = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        jobRepo.setDataSource(dataSource);
        jobRepo.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        transactionManager.setAllowCustomIsolationLevels(true);
        jobRepo.setTablePrefix("BATCH_");
        return jobRepo.getJobRepository();
    }

    protected void initialize() throws Exception {
        if (!this.initialized) {
            this.initialized = true;
        }
    }

    private class ReferenceTargetSource<T> extends AbstractLazyCreationTargetSource {
        private AtomicReference<T> reference;

        public ReferenceTargetSource(AtomicReference<T> reference) {
            this.reference = reference;
        }

        protected Object createObject() throws Exception {
            CronJobConfig.this.initialize();
            return this.reference.get();
        }
    }

    private class PassthruAdvice implements MethodInterceptor {
        private PassthruAdvice() {
        }

        public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
            return invocation.proceed();
        }
    }
}
```

DbConfig class:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager",
    basePackages = {"com.batch.common.config.batchcommonconfig"}
)
public class DbConfig {
    public DbConfig() {
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties(
        prefix = "spring.datasource"
    )
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @DependsOn({"transactionManager"})
    public DataSource h2DataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().url("jdbc:h2:mem:testdb").username("sa").password("").driverClassName("org.h2.Driver").build();
    }

    private Properties jpaHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", false);
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean(
        name = {"transactionManager"}
    )
    public JtaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JtaTransactionManager();
    }
}
```

TaskJobConfig class:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.DefaultTaskConfigurer;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.TaskConfigurer;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.repository.TaskExplorer;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.repository.TaskNameResolver;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.repository.TaskRepository;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.repository.support.SimpleTaskNameResolver;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.repository.support.TaskRepositoryInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableConfigurationProperties({CustomTaskProperties.class})
public class TaskJobConfig {

    protected static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(TaskJobConfig.class);
    @Autowired(
            required = false
    )
    private Collection<DataSource> dataSources;
    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
    @Autowired(
            required = false
    )
    private ApplicationArguments applicationArguments;
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public CustomTaskProperties taskProperties(){
        return new CustomTaskProperties();
    }
    private boolean initialized = false;
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;
    private TaskExplorer taskExplorer;

    public TaskJobConfig() {
        /***
         * Do nothing
         * */

    }

    @Bean
    public TaskRepository taskRepository() {
        return this.taskRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExplorer taskExplorer() {
        return this.taskExplorer;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskNameResolver taskNameResolver() {
        return new SimpleTaskNameResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskRepositoryInitializer taskRepositoryInitializer() {
        this.taskProperties().setTablePrefix("TASK_");
        this.taskProperties().setInitializeEnabled(true);
        TaskRepositoryInitializer taskRepositoryInitializer = new TaskRepositoryInitializer(this.taskProperties());
        DataSource initializerDataSource = this.getDefaultConfigurer().getTaskDataSource();
        if (initializerDataSource != null) {
            taskRepositoryInitializer.setDataSource(initializerDataSource);
        }

        return taskRepositoryInitializer;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    protected void initialize() {
        if (!this.initialized) {
            TaskConfigurer taskConfigurer = this.getDefaultConfigurer();
            logger.debug(String.format("Using %s TaskConfigurer", taskConfigurer.getClass().getName()));
            this.taskRepository = taskConfigurer.getTaskRepository();
            this.taskExplorer = taskConfigurer.getTaskExplorer();
            this.initialized = true;
        }
    }

    private TaskConfigurer getDefaultConfigurer() {
        this.taskProperties().setTablePrefix("TASK_");
        this.taskProperties().setInitializeEnabled(true);
        this.verifyEnvironment();
        int configurers = this.context.getBeanNamesForType(TaskConfigurer.class).length;
        if (configurers >= 1) {
            if (configurers == 1) {
                return (TaskConfigurer)this.context.getBean(TaskConfigurer.class);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Expected one TaskConfigurer but found " + configurers);
            }
        } else {
            DefaultTaskConfigurer taskConfigurer;
            if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(this.dataSources) && this.dataSources.size() == 1) {
                taskConfigurer = new DefaultTaskConfigurer((DataSource)this.dataSources.iterator().next(), this.taskProperties().getTablePrefix(), this.context);
            } else {
                taskConfigurer = new DefaultTaskConfigurer(this.taskProperties().getTablePrefix());
            }

            this.context.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("taskConfigurer", taskConfigurer);
            return taskConfigurer;
        }
    }

    private void verifyEnvironment() {
        int configurers = this.context.getBeanNamesForType(TaskConfigurer.class).length;
        long dataSourceCount = Arrays.stream(this.context.getBeanNamesForType(DataSource.class)).filter((name) -> {
            return !ScopedProxyUtils.isScopedTarget(name);
        }).count();
        if (configurers == 0 && dataSourceCount > 1L) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("To use the default TaskConfigurer the context must contain no more than one DataSource, found " + dataSourceCount);
        }
    }
}
```

CustomTaskConfigurer class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.DefaultTaskConfigurer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Component
public class CustomTaskConfigurer extends DefaultTaskConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    public CustomTaskConfigurer(@Qualifier("h2DataSource") DataSource dataSource)  {
        super(dataSource);
    }
}
```

CustomTaskProperties class:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.TaskProperties;


@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.cloud.task")
public class CustomTaskProperties extends TaskProperties {
    private static final int DEFAULT_CHECK_INTERVAL = 500;
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(TaskProperties.class);
    private String externalExecutionId;
    private Long executionid;
    private Long parentExecutionId;
    private String tablePrefix = "TASK_";
    private Boolean closecontextEnabled = false;
    private boolean singleInstanceEnabled = false;
    private int singleInstanceLockTtl = 2147483647;
    private int singleInstanceLockCheckInterval = 500;
    private Boolean initializeEnabled;

    public CustomTaskProperties() {
    }

    public String getExternalExecutionId() {
        return this.externalExecutionId;
    }

    public void setExternalExecutionId(String externalExecutionId) {
        this.externalExecutionId = externalExecutionId;
    }

    public Long getExecutionid() {
        return this.executionid;
    }

    public void setExecutionid(Long executionid) {
        this.executionid = executionid;
    }

    public Boolean getClosecontextEnabled() {
        return this.closecontextEnabled;
    }

    public void setClosecontextEnabled(Boolean closecontextEnabled) {
        this.closecontextEnabled = closecontextEnabled;
    }

    public String getTablePrefix() {
        return this.tablePrefix;
    }

    public void setTablePrefix(String tablePrefix) {
        this.tablePrefix = tablePrefix;
    }

    public Long getParentExecutionId() {
        return this.parentExecutionId;
    }

    public void setParentExecutionId(Long parentExecutionId) {
        this.parentExecutionId = parentExecutionId;
    }

    public boolean getSingleInstanceEnabled() {
        return this.singleInstanceEnabled;
    }

    public void setSingleInstanceEnabled(boolean singleInstanceEnabled) {
        this.singleInstanceEnabled = singleInstanceEnabled;
    }

    public int getSingleInstanceLockTtl() {
        return this.singleInstanceLockTtl;
    }

    public void setSingleInstanceLockTtl(int singleInstanceLockTtl) {
        this.singleInstanceLockTtl = singleInstanceLockTtl;
    }

    public int getSingleInstanceLockCheckInterval() {
        return this.singleInstanceLockCheckInterval;
    }

    public void setSingleInstanceLockCheckInterval(int singleInstanceLockCheckInterval) {
        this.singleInstanceLockCheckInterval = singleInstanceLockCheckInterval;
    }

    public Boolean isInitializeEnabled() {
        return this.initializeEnabled;
    }

    public void setInitializeEnabled(Boolean initializeEnabled) {
        this.initializeEnabled = initializeEnabled;
    }
}
```

batch-common-configuration pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.batch.common.config</groupId>
    <artifactId>batch-common-config</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>batch-common-config</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-task</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-task-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


</project>
```

error:

```
2021-02-23 14:05:57.056 ERROR 28492 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field transactionManager in com.batch.application.batchapplication.DemoCronJobConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 0
```

When I write these two projects as one project it works without any errors. It cannot create beans belonging to batch-common-configuration jar that I added externally. How can I overcome this problem? I am waiting for your advice. Thank you from now.

Comment: I don't know how it works when everything is put in a single project because I see no bean of type `JtaTransactionManager` defined in your config classes (and I don't see how one could be auto-configured by boot). Are you trying to put common bean definitions in `batch-common-configuration` and use them in other modules? If this is the case, you have two options: use Spring's classpath scanning or explicitly use `@Import(ClassContainingCommonBeansDefinedInBatchCommonConfigurationJar.class)` in your config classes.

Comment: I added the JTATransactionManager Bean to the DbConfig class. Also, I scan config classes with import annotation in SpringBatchApplication class. But still getting the same error.

Comment: You issue is related to how beans are being created and autowired. You don't need to add `@ComponentScan` if you explicitly use `@Import({CronJobConfig.class, TaskJobConfig.class,DbConfig.class})`. I do not recommend putting all annotations in the main config class, but import the minimum required on each config class. For example, if you need this datasource / transaction manager in `DemoCronJobConfiguration`, then you would better add `@Import(DbConfig.class)` on `DemoCronJobConfiguration` and not on the main class of your Spring Boot app which  is `SpringBatchApplication`.

Comment: I made updates on the project according to your suggestions. The Import and component annotation in the Spring Batch Application class has been removed and the Import annotation has been added to the DemoCronJobConfiguration class. Same error still occurs.